Twilsock Disconnected
I am trying to generate client in twilio , it was working fine , but suddenly I am facing error
const client = new Client(page.props.value.chat.token, { logLevel: 'debug' });
client.on("initFailed", ({ error }) => {
console.log("client initialized failed: " + error.message);
});


This is my code and getting error in the block
saying
2024-07-09T12:53:23.808Z Twilsock D: FSM: userConnect: disconnected --> connecting
ChatBox.vue:846 2024-07-09T12:53:23.812Z Twilsock D: Adding starting timepoint for 'twilsock.sdk.connect' event
ChatBox.vue:855 client initialized failed: Twilsock has disconnected.
ChatBox.vue:855 client initialized failed: Connection error: Invalid Access Token issuer/subject
